# How to make the colors on the heatmap chart to make it appear with scale values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

Can someone please take a look at my jsFiddle example and let me know why the colors on the heatmap chart don’t appear to scale with the values? There is some significant variation that I would expect to propagate into the chart.

Also, how can I adjust the tooltip so that the values for x,y are formatted in the same way as the axis values?

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/uadrecjg/

```
  var data1 = Papa.parse(document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML);
  var data2 = Papa.parse(document.getElementById('data2').innerHTML);

  function convertDataFromCsv(data) {
    var convData = [];
    data.forEach(function(elem) {
      convData.push({
        x: parseFloat(elem[0]),
        y: parseFloat(elem[1]),
        z: parseInt(elem[2])
      });
    });
    return convData;
  }
  Highcharts.chart('heatmap_container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap'
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          let seconds = this.value * 5;
          let t = new Date(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0);
          t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + this.value * 5);
          return `${t.getHours()}:${t.getMinutes()}:${t.getSeconds()}`
        }
      },
      tickInterval: 2
    },
    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return `${this.value/100}`;
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      margin: 0,
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      symbolHeight: 300
    },
    colorAxis: [{
      type: 'logarithmic',
      reversed: false,
      layout: 'vertical',
      maxColor: '#d52120',
      minColor: '#ffffff',
      min: 1,
      max: 100000,
    }, {
      type: 'logarithmic',
      reversed: false,
      layout: 'vertical',
      maxColor: '#1d843d',
      minColor: '#ffffff',
      min: 1,
      max: 100000,
    }],
    series: [{
      nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
      color:'#d52120',
      data: convertDataFromCsv(data1.data),
      turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE
    }, {
      nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
      color:'#1d843d',
      data: convertDataFromCsv(data2.data),
      turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE
    }, {
      colorAxis: 1
    }]
  });
```

**Current colors:**
For example, I see the same red and green colors.
[image: desired]

**Desired colors:**
The color green and red should go from light to dark to scale with the values as seen below
[image: current]

---

**UPDATE:**

This is how the chart looks like when importing the data from CSV files using the `z` value:

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/4w8r7chn/1/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` instead of `z` property:

```
  function convertDataFromCsv(data) {
    var convData = [];
    data.forEach(function(elem) {
      convData.push({
        x: parseFloat(elem[0]),
        y: parseFloat(elem[1]),
        value: parseInt(elem[2])
      });
    });
    return convData;
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rcaetjbw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.data

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, @ppotaczek. I see the z value did the trick of what I wanted when the data in defined in the html itself. However, when I tried to import data from the CSV files and parse it, it does not work as expected with the z value. Can you please look at this one and let me know the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/4w8r7chn/1/

Comment: Also updated the question with the pic of the chart of how it looks when importing the data from CSV files using z value

Comment: I figured it out. It works now as expected.